# jQuery keeps calling the function again and again

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dropdown

To show the **dropdown2** (It can be anything else), I am using the **dropdown1** `onchange="getFilterOption()"`.

**HTML** (To call function getFilterOption)

```
<select name="filter" data-userid="3" onchange="getFilterOption()">
    <option value="one">One</option>
    <option value="two">Two</option>
</select>";
```

**jQuery** (Function getFilterOption)

```
function getFilterOption() {
    $("#TargetFilterOption").append('<select id="filter_class1" name="filter1" data-privelesid1="".$priveles_id."" onchange="getFilter1(this.value)"><option value="">Filter</option><option value="All">All</option><option value="Yes">Yes</option><option value="No">No</option></select>');
};
```

**Problem**

When I use the dropdown for the first time (For example, I choose One), the program return some info and als the **dropdown2** (That what I want). But when I choose AGAIN another option (For example Two or something else) the program return the **dropdown2** again. So I get two **dropdown2**.

What do I have to do to show only once the **dropdown2**. Something like: if the **dropdown2** already added to page, don't call the function getFilterOption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `html()` function instead of `append()`. `html()` replaces the previous html, whereas `append()` append new html after existing.

```
$("#TargetFilterOption").html('<select id="filter_class1" name="filter1" data-privelesid1="".$priveles_id."" onchange="getFilter1(this.value)"><option value="">Filter</option><option value="All">All</option><option value="Yes">Yes</option><option value="No">No</option></select>')
```

Comment: you shouldn't append that each time.that will affect the performance

Answer (score 0):

if u want only to call one time use one function in jquery

```
$('select').one('change',function getFilterOption() 
{
$("#TargetFilterOption").append('<select id="filter_class1" name="filter1" data-privelesid1="".$priveles_id."" onchange="getFilter1(this.value)"><option value="">Filter</option><option value="All">All</option><option value="Yes">Yes</option><option value="No">No</option></select>');
});
```